# Angular ngIF not Working inside component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, angular5, angular8

i have a component called header but inside it my ngIf does not working and i have no idea why...

```
header.ts

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() subTitle: string;
  @Input() isPage: string;
```

header.html

```
<header>

  <div>
   //this *ngif does not work, if its 'yes' it hide the element and if i set to 'no' still hide
    <ion-buttons *ngIf="isPage === 'yes' " slot="start" (click)="goBack()" style="margin-left: 0.5em;">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </div>

  <div>
    // this work
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <h1>{{subTitle}}</h1>
  </div>

</header>
```

otherComponent.ts

```
<ion-content>
  <app-header title="lorum" subTitle="ipsum" isPage="yes" ></app-header>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use isPage as string? it's better to use boolean

Then you code changed to

```
@Input() isPage: Boolean;
```

And

```
<ion-buttons *ngIf="isPage" slot="start" (click)="goBack()" style="margin-left: 0.5em;">
```

And

```
<app-header [title]="lorum" [subTitle]="ipsum" [isPage]="true" ></app-header>
```

Comment: did wha u told me stiil dont work updated te ts and html
`<app-header title="lorum" subTitle="ipsum" [isPage]="true" ></app-header>`

Answer (score 1):

You should make `isPage` boolean and pass the input like this

```
<app-header [isPage]="true"></app-header>
```

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lqdbv) example

Comment: well i had to add CommonModule to my sharedModule

Comment: Did you add CommonModule after you saw the StackBlitz, if yes can you approve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your other component, you should assign the value of `isPage` to a variable, like this `const isPage = "yes";

Then do this

`<app-header [title]="App" [subTitle]="header" [isPage]=isPage></app-header>`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is having issues with this and the CommonModule solution above didn't apply to them.

I had the same issue because I created a new component with an embedded `*ngIf` inside of it running off of an internal class variable derived by logic inside of an `ngOnChanges()` method. Nothing I did would allow the ngIf to function to not render the component.

What fixed it was I had to kill my `ng serve` and restart my angular dev server. Once I did that the `*ngIf` started rendering correctly.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Angular is not well built because there are undocumented interferences when using built in directives inside new components. So much for a script that is supposed to compile and deploy fast and successfully. What a shame.

```js
import { Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {YearSuperContainer,Wrapper } from '../year-employee-model/year-employee-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-state-displayer',
  templateUrl: './state-displayer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./state-displayer.component.css']
})

export class StateDisplayerComponent 
{
    
    @Input() wrapper:Wrapper;
    visibleFlag:boolean = true;
    constructor()
    {
    }
    
    
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="visibleFlag" >Visible demon</div> <!-- never shows -->
```

Comment: are you sure that there're no problem in your code? has you checked the console to see if you get any error? Sure you declare your component in the proper Module? Angular is a well proved and mature framework, the most probably is you have a mistake in any place of your code (but it's impossible help more with your question)

Comment: There were errors into my code. I omitted some code that was referencing undefined object values inside ngif and it was solved.